Query for points where a particualr key exists in the payload
I am trying to query for points in Qdrant where the payload contains a particular key.
For eg. the payload looks likes this:
[{
  "data": {
    "some.key.one": "A textual value for the key"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "metadata_key": "metadata values"
  }
},
{
  "data": {
    "some.key.two": "Another textual value"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "metadata_key": "metadata values"
  }
}]

Here, I want to query for the payload that contains the key some.key.one in the payload.
I have tried using the following different queries but have gotten empty results:
Query#1:
{
  "limit": 10,
  "filter": {
    "must": [
      {
        "key": "data.some.key.one",
        "match": {
          "value": "*"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Query#2:
{
  "filter": {
    "must": [
      {
        "nested": {
          "key": "data",
          "filter": {
            "must": [
              {
                "key": "some.key.one",
                "match": {
                  "value": "*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

